# file creation process get corrupted

Tags: java, file-io, writer

I am stuck up in a odd situation I have to create a .dat file named abc.dat but the issue is that when I create it then in my c: drive I check that file with extension .dat is not created instead file with extension type _auto_file is created , please advise how can I correct my code so that .dat file extension get created...

```
if ( totaltsers.size()>0){
    try {// Generate a file
        //File file = new File(

        String finalfilename= abamfilepath+ getFileName();
        System.out.println(finalfilename);

        File file = new File(abamfilepath+ getFileName());
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        CharsetEncoder charsetEncoder = charset.newEncoder();
        charsetEncoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
        outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, charsetEncoder);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);

        if (file.exists()){
            file.delete();
        }

        for (tser tser : totaltsers) {
            for (toabj bk : books) {
                //if (tser.toabjdfr() == null)
                if((tser.toabjdfr() == null) &&(tser.ghjk() == null )){
                    bw.write("aaa");
                }
                else if (tser.toabjdfr() == null && tser.ghjk() != null ){
                    bw.write("bb");     
                }
                else if ( tser.toabjdfr() != null && tser.ghjk() == null){
                    bw.write("ccc");    
                }
            else
                    bw.write("ddd");
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }     
        bw.flush();
        bw.close(); 
        fileOutputStream.close();
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        String message = "Ate exception : " + e.getMessage();
        System.err.println(message);
        logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

below are the to construct the file name

```
public String getFileName() {
    return buildFileName();
}

private String buildFileName() {
    String  filename  = "abc";
    filename = filename+".dat";
    return filename;
```

i have done the changes as suggested but still not working.. but it is still not working please advise

```
String finalfilename= abamfilepath+ getFileName();
         System.out.println(finalfilename);
            File file = new File(abamfilepath + getFileName());
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getPath());
              OutputStreamWriter    outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
               BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter);
               if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }


             file.createNewFile();




    }
```

the issue  is still same dat file is not get created instead the file of type _auto_file gt created of size 0

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
File outFile = new File("numbers.dat");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));
    writer.write("12");
    writer.close();
```

If you are still unable to create the file,may be it is related to permission on windows root drive.Is your operating system installed on C drive?If yes can you please try changing the location where you are creating the file.